# Forms Like Authentication in WCF or Web API?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I currently have a MVC application that is using Forms Authentication.  I realize that you cannot self host a MVC application.  Business requirements dictate that my application has to be self hosted.  I was thinking of creating either a WCF or Web API application that is self hosted, where I can expose various endpoints.  However, the problem I am facing has to do with authentication.  In my MVC, I used Forms Auth, and allowed the user to use a form to enter credentials.  How can I do something similar in WCF or Web API.  I know how to render the HTML for the login page, etc, but the part that I am not familiar with is how to code up the smarts that anyone who tries to access one of my endpoints needs to be redirected to another service, so that I can do my thing to authenticate them.

I guess I'm trying to do something similar to the Forms Authentication redirect, but, within the context of WCF or Web API.  I started looking into message interceptors and route filters, but, still need to do some research.

Any ideas to point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Is actual requirement "don't use IIS" or "don't expose any HTTP endpoints" or something else? Changing from MVC/ASP.Net application to collection of static pages calling services on other domain is not trivial task - make sure you understand requirement correctly. (i.e. CORS is not available in all browsers - look for more pain).

Comment: The actual requirement is that we not use IIS.  It must be self hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Forms Authentication Control Flow is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx). This is what you need to implement using a [`DelegatingHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler.aspx) for ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: Thanks Alexander.  I discovered that.  So, is there anything similar if I used WCF REST services (WebHttpBinding) rather than Web API?

Comment: I don't know as I don't use WCF activily anymore.